# Excluding the last argument/parameter from a for loop

Tags: centos

I am looking to create a Shell Script that will loop through each argument/parameter except for the last one. Here is what I have so far:

```
for i in $@
do
      echo "$i"
done
```

This works well in terms of displaying all of the arguments after my ./script.sh command but I'm hoping there is a way of ignoring the last parameter or even any parameter of my choosing (ex. always ignoring the third parameter if there is one). To be clear, I'm more concerned about the last parameter/argument for now.

I'm new to scripting so I apologize if there is another post that contains this answer. I find being new at something usually means you don't know how to properly ask what you are looking for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't need to keep the parameters

```
while (( $# > 1 ))
do
  echo "$1"
  shift
done
```

If you want to keep the positional parameters untouched, you can keep a count

```
SKIP=$#

let x=1

for i
do
  if (( x != SKIP ))
  then
    echo "$i"
  fi
  let x=x+1
done
```

Answer (score 9):

CentOS probably has Bash, so if you can use it, you can run through a slice of the array:

```
for x in "${@:1:$# - 1}" ; do 
    echo do something with "$x"
done
```

[The `${@:n:m}` notation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) takes the `m` positional parameters starting at number `n`. We pick their total number from `$#` and decrement by one to ignore the last parameter. The offset and length are taken as arithmetic expressions as in `$((...))`, so we can do the arithmetic right there, as  Stéphane commented below.
Array indices usually start from zero, but in the case of `$@` starting at zero would bring the shell name from `$0` in and that's not what we want.

Note that you are highly likely to want to quote the `$@` or `${@:n:m}` expressions to prevent further splitting your arguments.

Comment: Or just `"${@:1:$#-1}"` (you need `${@:1:$# -1}` in `zsh` other wise `$#-1` would be taken as `${#-}1`). See also `"$@[1,-2]"` or `"${@:1:-1}"` in `zsh`

Answer (score 3):

```
skip_last() {
   p=$1; shift

   for i
   do
      set ${1+"$@"} "$p"; p=$1; shift
   done

   for i
   do
      # do something with i when i != last now
      echo "$i"
   done
}
# and then...
skip_last "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [for loop](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html#Looping-Constructs) that sets a variable `i` to `1`, `2`, ... `n-1`, and use an [indirect expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Evaluating_indirect.2Freference_variables) to turn that into `$1`, `$2`, ..., `$n-1`.

```
for ((i=1; i<$#; i++)); do
    echo "${!i}"
done
```